# How to run console app on other windows form project

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Hi i have a existing console app in c# and win form project on the same solution

Is there a way to run the console app on my winform providing the readkey needed on the console app from the textbox on my win form
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible

Check Process.Start() on MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_

Just start the process and pass your textbox value as argument

Comment: But can i get a value of a variable from the opened app on process start?

Comment: of course, see process.StandardOutput (for ex. on msdn)